# cannot show element next to checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have HTML like so:

```
<input type="checkbox" class="chk-class" /> Click to enable<br/>
<div class="hidden">Hidden content here</div>
```

I want to reveal the content when the checkbox is clicked. So here's the JS:

```
$('.chk-class').bind('click', function(){
    $(this).closest('.hidden').show();
});
```

Why isn't this working?

PS: I do not want to use IDs. I want this to be dynamically assigned as I have multiple checkboxes.

Comment: $(this).next().show();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the second next sibling from what I can see

```
$('.chk-class').on('change', function(){
    $(this).next().next().toggle();
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/FtNb3/)

Another way is(If you are not sure about the elements between the checkbox and hidden)

```
$('.chk-class').on('change', function () {
    $(this).nextUntil('.hidden').last().next().toggle();
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/vGHFb/)

Comment: user, I think here is your solution +1 better than mine

Answer (score 0):

closest moves upwards use `next`

```
$(this).next().show();
```

**EDIT** use `nextAll('selector:first')` to show just next element with specific `class/id etc`

```
$(this).nextAll('.hidden:first').show()
```

Comment: there's some text and a <br/> between the checkbox and the div. i want to be able to just find the next element by class name "hidden"

Comment: @user2914191 you need to share your correct markup if you want a solution

Comment: `nextAll` with `selector:first` worked for me, thanks

Answer (score 0):

First you should hide your `hidden` div with display: none

```
.hidden {
    display: none;
}
```

then

```
$(".chk-class").click(function(){
    $(".hidden").css("display","block");
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/e5Jvg/

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.chk-class').change(function(){
    $(this).next('.hidden').toggle();
});
```